# This expression is not callable. Not all constituents of type 'string | ((searchTerm: string) => Promise<void>) | []' are callable

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have my custom **useResults** hook like this

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import yelp from '../api/yelp';

export default () => {
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');

  const searchApi = async (searchTerm:string) => {
    console.log('Hi there!');
    try {
      const response = await yelp.get('/search', {
        params: {
          limit: 50,
          term: searchTerm,
          location: 'san jose'
        }
      });
      setResults(response.data.businesses);
    } catch (err) {
      setErrorMessage('Something went wrong');
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    searchApi('pasta');
  }, []);

  return [searchApi, results, errorMessage];
};
```

in my Search screen I import my custom hook and do a destructuring like this

```
const [searchApi, errorMessage, results ] = useResults();
```

But I can't call my searchApi method from JSX code like below (I can call **errorMessage** and **results**).

```
<SearchBar term={term} onTermChange={setTerm} onTermSubmit={()=>searchApi(term)}/>
```

I'm getting this error

> This expression is not callable.
> Not all constituents of type 'string | ((searchTerm: string) => Promise) | never[]' are callable.
> Type 'string' has no call signatures

How to pass the "**searchApi**" function to "**onTermSubmit**" prop in my "**SearchBar**" component ?
as you can see "**searchApi**" is an async function

Below is my package.json

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@types/axios": "^0.14.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "expo": "~40.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.3",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-40.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.8.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.13.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.1.9",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.15.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.3",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0",
    "@types/react": "~16.9.35",
    "@types/react-dom": "~16.9.8",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.63.2",
    "typescript": "~4.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Below is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "strict": true
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 57, accepted):

FYI, in order to keep elements in an array to keep position without allowing `tsc` infers thing you can set it as fixed by setting `as const`:

```js
return [searchApi, results, errorMessage] as const;
```

Comment: omg, it is really helpfull ^_^

Comment: Aw man, I liked the days where I could add booleans and integers in JS. Now I gotta do stuff like this

Answer (score 6):

Because you are returning

```
 return [searchApi, results, errorMessage];
```

and not

```
 return { searchApi, results, errorMessage };
```

There is importance for the position of the destructed value, and not to the string key you named.

Therefore by

```
const [searchApi, errorMessage, results ] = useResults();
```

`errorMessage` and `results` are points on each other and not on themself

Comment: why I cant return an array ?
Is it possible to return an array ?

Comment: you can, just be careful to destruct the values in the order you return them